# How can I spread an object's properties in jq?

Tags: json, object, key, jq

If I need to access the properties of an object, I'm currently accessing each property manually:

```
echo '{"a": {"a1":1, "a2": 2}, "b": 3}' | jq '{a1:.a.a1, a2: .a.a2,b}'
{
  "a1": 1,
  "a2": 2,
  "b": 3
}
```

I'd like to avoid specifying every property. Is there an equivalent to the Object spread operator in JS, something like `jq '{...a, b}'`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add objects together to combine their contents. If a key exists in both the left and right objects the value from the right object will remain.

```
echo '{"a": {"a1":1, "a2": 2}, "b": 3}' | jq '.a+{b}'
{
  "a1": 1,
  "a2": 2,
  "b": 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a completely generic solution:

```
[..|objects|with_entries(select(.value|type!="object"))]|add
```

Or if you want a depth-first approach, replace `add` by `reverse|add`.

The above of course comes with the understanding that `add` resolves conflicts in a lossy way. If you don’t want any lossiness, choose a different method for combining objects, or maybe don’t combine them at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that only examines the top-level values, without referring to any key by name:

```
with_entries(if .value|type=="object" then .value|to_entries[] else . end)
```

For the example, this produces:

```
{
  "a1": 1,
  "a2": 2,
  "b": 3
}
```

Note that even though this solution doesn't use `add` explicitly, it comes with a similar caveat about key collisions.